# GraphQL MockList is not a constructor

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

```
const { ApolloServer, gql, MockList }  = require("apollo-server");
const typeDefs = gql`
    scalar Date

    """
    An Object that contain the ski day info
    """
    type SkiDay{
        "A ski day ID"
        id:ID!
        date:Date!
        mountain:String!
    }
    type Query{
        totalDays : Int!
        allDays:[SkiDay!]!
        condition:Conditions 
    }
    enum Conditions{
        POWER
        HAVY
        ICE
        THIN
    }
    input AddDayInput{
        id:ID!
        date:Date!
        condition:Conditions
    }
    type RemoveDayPayload{
        day:SkiDay!
        removed: Boolean
        totalBefore:Int
        totalAfter:Int
    }
    type Mutation{
        addDay(input:AddDayInput!):SkiDay
        removeDay(id:ID!) : RemoveDayPayload!
    }
    type Subscription{
        newDay: SkiDay!
    }
`;

const mocks = {
    Date: () => "02/10/2023",
    String: () => "Cool!",
    Query: () => ({
        allDays: () => new MockList(1) // **<< this is the place**
    }),
}
const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    mocks
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) =>
    console.log(`server running at ${url}`)
);
```

package.json dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "apollo-server": "^3.12.0",
    "graphql": "^16.7.1",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1"
  }
```

Error:

```
"extensions": {
                "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
                "exception": {
                    "stacktrace": [
                        "TypeError: MockList is not a constructor",
                        "    at allDays (/Users/user/user/graphql/ski-count/index.js:49:24)",
                        "    at MockStore.generateFieldValueFromMocks (/Users/user/user/graphql/ski-count/node_modules/@graphql-tools/mock/cjs/MockStore.js:313:29)",
                        "    at MockStore.generateFieldValue (/Users/user/user/graphql/ski-count/node_modules/@graphql-tools/mock/cjs/MockStore.js:289:34)",
                        "    at MockStore.getImpl (/Users/user/user/graphql/ski-count/node_modules/@graphql-tools/mock/cjs/MockStore.js:146:30)",
                        "    at MockStore.get (/Users/user/user/graphql/ski-count/node_modules/@graphql-tools/mock/cjs/MockStore.js:35:29)",
                        "    at mockResolver (/Users/user/user/graphql/ski-count/node_modules/@graphql-tools/mock/cjs/addMocksToSchema.js:104:26)",
                        "    at field.resolve (/Users/user/user/graphql/ski-count/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/utils/schemaInstrumentation.js:56:26)",
                        "    at executeField (/Users/user/user/graphql/ski-count/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:492:20)",
                        "    at executeFields (/Users/user/user/graphql/ski-count/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:414:22)",
                        "    at executeOperation (/Users/user/user/graphql/ski-count/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:344:14)"
                    ]
                }
            }
```

I've checked the apollo-server/src/export.ts file, and there's no export function called MockList.

```
export {
  gql,
  GraphQLOptions,
  Config,
  GraphQLSchemaModule,
  // Errors
  ApolloError,
  toApolloError,
  SyntaxError,
  ValidationError,
  AuthenticationError,
  ForbiddenError,
  UserInputError,
} from 'apollo-server-core';

export { CorsOptions } from 'apollo-server-express';
```

Not sure that could be the reason for this. Source is [here](https://github.com/ekodikara/grapql-skicount)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the MockList resolver has been deprecated and eliminated in Apollo Server 3.X.

For Apollo server 3.x according to the documentation to automate mocking a list, return an array of the desired length. Using [...new Array(n)] is convenient syntax for creating an array that contains n copies of desired type

[Apollo 3.x Mocking a list](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v3/testing/mocking/#using-lists-in-mocks):

Try this :

```
const mocks = {
    Date: () => "02/10/2023",
    String: () => "Cool!",
    Query: () => ({
        allDays: () => [...new Array(5)]
    })
}
```